# PyTorch RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

Purely for learning, I'd like to get the following code to work, without a DataLoader. I use Huggingface transformers regularly yet I struggle with PyTorch dimensions all the time so I have started with some simple projects from the book "Deep Learning with PyTorch."  One of the problems from the book suggested using a wine quality dataset on a super simple linear model.  I have toiled with the dimensions of the data, which I think is the source of my error:

`RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (3919x1 and 11x100)`

Data is available [here](http://mng.bz/90Ol)

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.optim as optim

import torch.nn as nn

wine_path = "winequality-white.csv"
wine_quality_numpy = np.loadtxt(wine_path, dtype=np.float32, delimiter=";",
                         skiprows=1)

col_list = next(csv.reader(open(wine_path), delimiter=';'))

wineq = torch.from_numpy(wine_quality_numpy)

# print(wineq.shape, wineq.dtype)

data = wineq[:, :-1]
target = wineq[:, -1]
target = target.unsqueeze(1)

n_samples = wine_quality_numpy.shape[0]
n_val = int(0.2 * n_samples)

shuffled_indices = torch.randperm(n_samples)

train_indices = shuffled_indices[:-n_val]
val_indices = shuffled_indices[-n_val:]

target_train = target[train_indices]
data_train = data[train_indices]

target_val = target[val_indices]
data_val = data[val_indices]

seq_model = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
    ('hidden_linear', nn.Linear(11, 100)),
    ('hidden_activation', nn.Tanh()),
    ('output_linear', nn.Linear(100, 7))
]))

def training_loop(n_epochs, optimizer, model, loss_fn, target_train, target_val,
                  data_train, data_val):
    for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
        t_p_train = model(target_train) # <1>
        loss_train = loss_fn(t_p_train, data_train)

        t_p_val = model(t_u_val) # <1>
        loss_val = loss_fn(t_p_val, data_val)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_train.backward() # <2>
        optimizer.step()

        if epoch == 1 or epoch % 1000 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Training loss {loss_train.item():.4f},"
                  f" Validation loss {loss_val.item():.4f}")


optimizer = optim.SGD(seq_model.parameters(), lr=1e-3) # <1>

training_loop(
    n_epochs = 5000, 
    optimizer = optimizer,
    model = seq_model,
    loss_fn = nn.MSELoss(),
    target_train = target_train,
    target_val = target_val, 
    data_train = data_train,
    data_val = data_val)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check the shape of `target_train`. It should have shape `(3919, 11)`, given that the dataset has 11 features. Instead you have `(3919, 1)`, which means you're passing a vector of a single feature, but your first hidden layer expects 11.

Comment: Hi @NikhilKumar thanks for getting back to me. The `data_train.shape` is `torch.Size([3919, 11])` While the target_train is just the classification labels. Should I add empty values to expand the shape?

Comment: Ok. Where are you passing `data_train` to your model (`seq_model`)?

Comment: Yes, though I realize it is not obvious are a renamed variables before posting(!) for clarity. I still have the same issue. `t_c_train` should be `data_train` and `t_c_val` should be `data_val`.

Comment: I had the labels and the data backwards it is working!! sorry for the waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

In my haste I had the training data and labels swapped.  Here is the fixed section.

```
seq_model = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
('hidden_linear', nn.Linear(11, 100)),
('hidden_activation', nn.Tanh()),
('output_linear', nn.Linear(100, 7))
]))

def training_loop(n_epochs, optimizer, model, loss_fn, target_train, target_val,
                  data_train, data_val):
    for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
        t_p_train = model(data_train) # <1>
        loss_train = loss_fn(t_p_train, target_train)

        t_p_val = model(data_val) # <1>
        loss_val = loss_fn(t_p_val, target_val)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_train.backward() # <2>
        optimizer.step()

        if epoch == 1 or epoch % 1000 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Training loss {loss_train.item():.4f},"
                  f" Validation loss {loss_val.item():.4f}")
```